# javascript OOP get from parent object

Tags: javascript, oop, parent

How can I access the parent attribute of a child object like this?

```
    var foo = function foo(input){ this.input = input; };
    function bar(input){ return new foo(input); }
    foo.prototype = {
        baz : {
            qux : function(){
                alert(this.parent.input );
            }
        },
        corge : function(){
                alert(this.input );
        }
    }

bar('test').corge(); //alerts 'test'

bar('test').baz.qux(); //errors 'this.parent is undefined'
```

Comment: Which object are you expecting `this.parent` to reference? In what world does `bar('test').corge();` alert `'test'`? Not in this one.

Comment: I don't even believe that you get an alert with `test`. Where to you set `this.obj`?

Comment: @MattBall Ideally the root object 'foo'. I know I am writing it wrong, and OOP is still new to me. I would like bar('test').baz.quz() to alert 'test'.

Comment: @FelixKling I have edited my question to make more sense. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think the [Details of the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) chapter in the MDC JavaScript guide is worth reading.

Comment: JavaScript does not have a way to access the `parent` of a property. That property could be attached to multiple objects so there's no way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access `this.obj` for a child object like this?

You can't.

There is one `baz` regardless of how many `new foo` there are, so there is no way to map from `this` which typically points to the singleton `foo.prototype.baz` to a specific instance of `foo`.

It looks like you probably meant to create a `baz` per instance of `foo`.

Try this

```
function foo(input) {
   this.baz = {
     parent: this,
     qux: quxMethod
   };
   this.input = input;
}
foo.prototype.corge = function () { alert(this.input); };
function quxMethod() {
  alert(this.parent.input);
}
```

Comment: you are correct in your two simple words "You can't". There are ways around it. But that is what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try defining `baz` like so:</strike>

```
  baz : (function(){
        var parent = this;
        return {
           qux : function(){
               alert(parent.obj);
           }
        }
    })()
```

---

#### Update:

I believe this will do what you want it to do:
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rKcwP/
Code:

```
var foo = function foo(input) {
    this.input = input;
};

function bar(input) {
    return new foo(input);
}
foo.prototype = {
    baz: function() {
        var parent = this;
        return {
            qux: function() {
                alert(parent.input);
            }
        }
    },
    corge: function() {
        alert(this.input);
    }
}

bar('test').corge(); //alerts 'test'
bar('test').baz().qux(); //alerts 'test'
```

Comment: Also I have never seen syntax like this (function(){})() what are the second sent or parenthesis for?

Comment: I would prefer baz.qux(); vs baz().qux();

Comment: @Neal, Creating an object per use of baz will throw away any state that `baz` encapsulates.  If you think that's within the bounds of the OP, why not do away with `baz` entirely, and just move `baz`'s methods onto `foo.prototype`?